# Air filter for 1.4 tdci Ford Fiesta

Tags: engine, noise, air-intake, air-filter, air

i have a 1.4 TDCI Ford Fiesta mk7 and I would like to know if I can install a cone shaped air filter  in this engine in order to have a little bit more sound without looking too "showy".

My engine look like this:
[image]

Where do I have to install the filter?

Comment: Where the air filter box connects to the MAF sensor.

Comment: It's a lovely 1.4 TDCI Ford Fiesta, and that's all it will be. People will think you have a hole in the exhaust, until you explain that you modified the front end to defeat the latest noise-reducing technology, much kudos (perhaps). BTW if you modify the car, you must tell the insurance company.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to dig into your pockets a bit and replace the entire airbox assembly, possibly with, a new map sensor that was designed  for the new air box. There is no quick and easy way to add a cone filter to this motor, due to the way Ford has designed your air box assembly.

Comment: All right thank you :) where i can find some informations?

Comment: If i replace the air filter inner panel with a panel shaped from k&n will the sound get better? Thank you.

Comment: @Raydar - only you can answer that. "Better" means very different things to different people. With that Fiesta, there is nothing you can do that will dramatically change it - it's a small Ford engine.